# How to associate list of prerequisites with list of targets in Make?

Tags: makefile

Say I have:

```
TARGETS = a.o b.o c.o
SOURCES = F1/a.c F2/F3/b.c c.c
```

I want to obtain:

```
a.o: F1/a.c
  gcc $< -c
b.o: F2/F3/b.c
  gcc $< -c
c.o: c.c
  gcc $< -c
```

I would like a compact expression to do the job, something like:

```
$(TARGETS): $(SOURCES)
   #Appropriate compile command
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `VPATH` to tell make about source directories and then use a simple pattern rule:

```
TARGETS := a.o b.o c.o
VPATH := F1:F2/F3 # Use ; instead of : on Windows

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

(or even omit the rule altogether, make implicit rules will work fine in this case)

But if you have files that are named in the same way in different paths that's not going to work (it'd just pick the first one it finds). This works by zipping the lists like you asked:

```
TARGETS := a.o b.o c.o
SOURCES := F1/a.c F2/F3/b.c c.c

$(TARGETS):
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

list-rem = $(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)
pairmap = $(and $(strip $2),$(strip $3),$(call \
        $1,$(firstword $2),$(firstword $3))$(call \
        pairmap,$1,$(call list-rem,$2),$(call list-rem,$3)))
gen-prereq = $(eval $1: $2)

$(call pairmap,gen-prereq,$(TARGETS),$(SOURCES))
```

I defined an explicit rule which compiles its prerequisite, but I didn't give it any prerequisites. I then defined a `pairmap` that takes a function name and two lists and calls the function for each pair of elements. It's recursive and is helped by `list-rem`, which takes the first element out of a list. `gen-prereq` sets its second argument as a prerequisite of the target specified by its first one. All that's left then is calling `pairmap` over `gen-prereq`, passing the targets as the first list and the sources as the second.

Another feasible and simpler way is:

```
TARGETS := a.o b.o c.o
SOURCES := F1/a.c F2/F3/b.c c.c

$(TARGETS):
    gcc -c $< -o $@

$(foreach x,$(join $(addsuffix :,$(TARGETS)),$(SOURCES)),$(eval $x))
```

Which works by joining targets and sources together with a `:` in between them (prerequisite) and eval'ing each one.

Comment: @user3228136 Be careful though, if you have common names (e.g. dir1/a.c and dir2/a.c) it will blow up.